# 4 or 5: is thumb a finger? Distribution across languages

Tags: reference-request, linguistic-typology, lexical-semantics, numerals

Researching the origins of counting systems, I came across the question I cannot seem to find an answer for: what is the typological distribution of languages that consider thumb a finger (5 fingers on hand) vs. those that do not (4 fingers, thumb is not a finger). English is in the latter category, although since recently, due to its status as a *de facto* international language, it seems to have become more fluid on this.

Lexically, there seems to be not a clear-cut distinction among even language families. Danish (Germanic) has *tommelfinger* for the thumb, and Russian (Slavic) has большой палец *bol'shoy palec*, “great finger”, while Slovenian (also Slavic) uses the same root *palec* for “thumb,” and has a non-cognate *prst* for “finger.” Romance languages seem to prefer a separate root for the thumb, after Latin, but again, Romanian has *deget mare*, “great finger” for the thumb, making it a “thumb-unaware” language. There are signs, such as remnants of the dual declension of Russian numerals for two to four and Latin *octo*, and the cognacy of *nine* and *new*, suggesting that PIE placed more weight on counting in fours and not fives when its counting developed (a relation to the number of fingers seems likely to be a factor), but the modern daughter languages fluctuate between 4 and 5 rather non-systematically.

Of course, having a separate root lexeme for the thumb may be tangential to finger counting. It is possible that of “thumb-aware” languages, some count 5 fingers, despite having a separate root for the thumb, and some do 4. Cf. English has *pinky* but it is still unquestionably a finger. This is the main, the most interesting question of my research: how many fingers languages count on a hand.

Unfortunately, [WALS](http://wals.info/feature) does not have this category. There are distributions for languages that lexically distinguish hand and finger (topics 130A and B), but this monumental atlas seems shy on semantic topics in general, so this question may be even out of their scope.

**Can anyone help with references to the research on the typological classification of languages into “4-finger” and “5-finger” categories? A wide, methodologically consistent review would be the best** (WALS is a great example). As I am dealing with the *development* of counting, references to reconstructed and ancient languages would also be very helpful.

Splitting the latter (5-finger) category into those having and not having a root lexeme for thumb is secondary and less important to me currently, but I believe, for the general nature of SE questions, would also lie in the scope. This should be related in any case.

Comment: Can you name one recorded language that counts 4/8/16 fingers?

Comment: I did. English. *It's [...] more accurate to describe a thumb as one of five digits that we have on each hand, rather than as a finger.* -- https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/explore/is-a-thumb-a-finger

Comment: It's not clear to me that the idea that the thumb is not a finger is totally accurate for any modern speaker with regard to English, and I wonder if it was ever so. (The idea that the more restrictive definition must be "more accurate", which seems to be assumed by the author of that quote, doesn't seem quite right to me.) Consider the established expression "to snap one's fingers": the plural "fingers" here seems like it must include the thumb, unless you argue that the expression can only be used to refer to snapping with both hands. Does that make this an "inaccurate" expression?

Comment: The Google Ngram Viewer seems to indicate that "ten fingers" has been more common than "eight fingers" since at least 1800, although "four fingers" is more common than "five fingers" during the same period. The Oxford English Dictionary quotes a source from "a1500" that says "The fifte fynger is the thowmbe", so it seems clear that the inclusive definition has been used at least since the 16th century.

Comment: @sumelic I certainly hear you, and even noted English inconsistency on this question. Some speakers have 4 fingers and a thumb, some have 5, and neither sounds weird to me. This is an example why the question is typologically complex. How would a Bushmen linguist classify English? The same argument applies in reverse, only worse, as e.g. Polynesian lexical semantics varies from village to village. And of reconstructed languages we have only indirect evidence, like the PIE counting pattern (8 is dual in number, 9 is “new” something). And try to prove that this has any relation to fingers!

Comment: It's interesting to note also that the idea that the more restrictive definition is "more accurate" doesn't seem to be present in the OED entry for the word "finger", which gives the first definition as "Each of the five slender jointed parts attached to either hand; (also, in narrower sense) each of the four excluding the thumb." I assume the Oxford Dictionaries' "Random questions" are answered by knowledgeable people, but I still wouldn't expect a post like this to be as trustworthy as an OED dictionary entry.

Comment: @sumelic: Yup. Who needs prescriptivists! :) The question is hard to answer for some languages, for English exceptionally so (one reason of many being a great variety of foreign dialects of the former Empire that bring native mental body plans into acquired language and pass it on down generations); also, the modern mind is too much affected by the scientific ideas of classification and strict definitions. So in this one particular language, the idea of thumb as a non-finger seems on the way out. But my question is inherently about a wide assay of the topic.

Comment: @kkm No, if you ask English speakers "How many fingers do you have?" most will say "Ten".  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=all+ten+fingers%2C+all+eight+fingers  Is there an actual unequivocal example of a so-called 4-finger language or culture?  Speakers of which will perceive "Ten" as wrong?

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer. Indo-European *oḱtō “eight” is probably a dual noun meaning “two spans”, that is: two sets of four fingers.

Comment: @fdb Understood from the question, but PIE is not a recorded language, let alone a living one.  OP is asking for a list of living languages that fulfill criteria x, but I am still waiting to hear just one.

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer: I see the point, and at the same time I do not. As I noted in the Q, English is inconsistent, and I cannot give you an example of a 4-finger language that would be *unquestionably consistent*. If I could answer, there would be no Q. If the implication of your question is that there are no such languages, I would not argue if that were in fact true, but then I still need a reference. And, since the question is methodologically hard, due to complications exemplified by English, a consistent methodology of a study I am looking for is utmostly important. contd...

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer: Any objects in scientific studies (I regard linguistics a science) are defined within theories, and there is no such thing as "root", or "syllable", or a "4-finger language" absent a sound framework within which such a thing lives. So in a certain framework English would be a 4-finger language, in another it might be not, and the question is moot, lacking an exact method of such a study. WALS is a great example: a whole chapter defining a framework, and references to papers agreeing with the method accepted in the chapter. I am really looking for something as deep as it.

Comment: @kkm I am not arguing x does not exist. My point is, you are asking for a global list of x before we have just one reasonably concrete example of x.

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer: I am not asking for a list, but a reference to a typological study, if one exists (and I would be very surprised if this topic has not been researched). As you find that my example of English not *reasonable* (or not *concrete*, but I believe that it is less arguable, however wide a variety of languages “English” denotes), then I should ask for your operational definition of *reasonableness*. And this is indeed a big part of my question: I am looking for a study that is sound in its method. Does this clarification help you answer my question?

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer: I mean, if you have some works in mind, but not sure they are a match, why do not you just give the citations? I am almost sure they would help me, even if not strictly on topic.

Comment: @kkm Pardon, yes, I understand now.  No data or studies are known to me.  My instinct would be to apply tests like the "all eight fingers" test to datasets for many languages, but that does not help much for the languages where counting was being developed, assuming counting usually comes well before writing.

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer: No worries, the question appeared much simpler to me as well when I approached it at first. For one, there are (mostly *were*, sadly) American Indian languages with quaternary counting, but those who documented them while they were live 100+ years ago did not manage to ask the speakers how many fingers they had on each hand (with rare exceptions, which can hardly be trusted). Those that survived, quickly adopted the decimal system from us the invaders. Digging through *American Anthropologist* of the era all but makes me literally cry over the loss.

Comment: @kkm Yes, it's not necessarily a property of a language per se, could be highly unstable under contact.

Comment: No, counting isn't a property of language. Pirahã, for instance, has no numerals, nor counting. So they wouldn't fit into either category. As you say, the question is more complex than expected.

Comment: Another thing which is interesting is that counting on fingers differs: in some cultures they count `1`=index, `2`=middle, `3`=ring, `4`=pinkie, `5`=thumb, and in other they count `1`=thumb, `2`=index, `3`=middle, `4`=ring, `5`=pinkie. I have not seen anything else, but it might be interesting to find a culture with even another order, such as starting with the pinkie.

Comment: ...and in many languages the word for *finger* is related to *digit* - https://www.etymonline.com/word/digit - http://etimologias.dechile.net/?dedo - as digits are the basic counting tool :)

Comment: Saw this on Etymonline's entry for [thumb](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=thumb): "Compare Greek megas daktylos "thumb," but Greek also had antikheir, literally "what is opposite the fingers." " For your actual question, see this JSTOR daily article: https://daily.jstor.org/where-do-finger-names-come-from/

Comment: @cmw Very interesting, even if tangential! I have to reject the penis etymology of _impudicus/obscenus,_ unless of very late origin: erect penis talismans, _fascini,_ were ubiquitous to ward off evil spirits, as was _manu fica,_ used to this day in a few Romance cultures. The 2nd hypothesis is also unconvincing: 1) other fingers likely work as good for female masturbation, alone or in combination; 2) the exact technique had hardly been widely discussed in the society to be such a common knowledge 2500 y. before Pornhub to end up as the etymon. I'd rather first look into religious connections.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about the idiom “five finger discount” that is popular in at least modern English? Giving someone a “high five” also indirectly refers to the five fingers of one’s hand. To me the “thumb” has always been a specialised name for one of the five fingers. Let’s not forget that “the pinky” also has a distinct name that doesn’t include the word “finger” in it, like the other 3 fingers have. As a native speaker of English I never had a doubt about the thumb being one of the five fingers. I wonder if that is true for English speakers from all regions.

Comment: Conclusive arguments indeed, thanks for the insight! How didn't I think of “high five?”

Comment: Even *middle finger* implies 3rd of 5.

Comment: worth noting that "pinky" is not generally used in British English, where it is usually called the "little finger"

Comment: Be careful, @Tristan: it is not generally used in **English** English, but it is in (at least some) Scottish varieties. I don't  know about the rest of the British Isles: I doubt if it is used in Wales, and I have no idea about Ireland.

Comment: "High five" seems to be a pretty direct reference

Comment: @ColinFine huh, I didn't know that about Scotland! It is also sometimes heard in England these days (increasingly so I'd say), although little finger is still dominant